# Creating Excel *2007* Spreadsheet from Access 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

We are running VBA in Access 2007 and trying to create an Excel 2007 spreadsheet.  We are using the following format:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Table/Query Name Here", "FileNameHere".

as
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "DimWebSample_Final", gsExportFilePath & gsExportFileNameBody & "_" & Month(gdDate) & Day(gdDate) & Year(gdDate) & "_" & gsDatasetExportFileSuffix(giDatasetID) & ".xls", True
```

I have Excel 2007 on my computer, but using acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 creates Excel 87 or 2000 spreadsheets according to Access 2007 help.  That is what we get.  The help does not list another acSpreadsheetTypeExcelnn constanct to useu for 2007 results.

How would I get it to creates an Excel **2007** spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excel 2007 introduces](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/introduction-to-new-file-name-extensions-HA010006935.aspx) two new formats xlsb and xlsx. So you have to pick either `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` or `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` If your file extension doesn't match the type then Excel will complain when it opens it so you should also make sure your extension is correct.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
             "Table1", _
              "Table1.xlsb"
```

or

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
     "Table1", _
     "Table1.xlsx"
```

Comment: @Lars I'm glad I was able to help. BTW at the risk of seeming to lobby for my answer to be accepted, there is a system for [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which will become important to you if you ask 4 or more questions.

Answer (score 0):

On opening the xlsx file the following message shown
`found unreadable content in 'Table1.xlsx'`

After clicking the `Yes` button to repair the file the following message shown
`Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part`

*What* happened? and *How* could I prevent this?